# lighttpd virtual host config

Tags: lighttpd, virtualhost

Trying to get these two vhosts set up correctly.  I have two sites on this domain that i'm hosting:  www.example.com/example.com and test.example.com.

How do I get both of these to work in my vhost definitions?

I have:

$HTTP["host"] == "test.example.com" {

and

$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|.)example.com$" { (I think this is for *.example.com)

It always goes to the second one, even if I am trying to go to test.example.com.  I need to be able to host www.example.com/example.com and test.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping them. The last match wins.